# How big is an AF-Point in a Nikon camera?

Tags: nikon, raw, autofocus, image-processing, continuous-autofocus

I have a Nikon D7500 and am looking for information regarding the size, in pixels, of each individual AF-Point in the 51-point AF system.

When stored in NEF files, Nikon references their AF-points in "bingo" terminology. A1, E6, B4 etc. They do not give any information as to the exact width, height, and location on the image sensor. Where can I find this information?

Comment: I have no knowledge of the intricacies of Nikon AF systems, but if they are anything like Canon's there are no AF "points". There are rectangular areas of sensitivity (two rectangles at 90° for "cross-type Points", four rectangles at 45° for "dual cross type points") that can vary widely in size and shape from one "point" to another in the same camera.

Comment: This sounds like an [X→Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/348605). What is the basic photographic problem you think you can solve with this information?

Answer (score 1):

The Nikon focus points map like this. What that means in terms of image pixel size IDK... a lot more than 1.

FWIW, this is nothing like how the AF sensor/sensor lines actually look/work.

[image]

The exif for a D850 image reads like this:

AF Area Mode : Group Area

Phase Detect AF : On (153-point)

AF Points Used : E12

Primary AF Point : C12

Which means: Group AF, centered around C12, E12 reported in focus

[image]

And the image review looks like this:

[image]

This is what the 51pt PDAF sensor actually looks like.
[image]